# Webrtc status stuck on "connecting" and status become "failed"

Tags: webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I can't let two Android devices connect to each other even if both devices are connected to same wifi. In sometime it is successful to connect, but most of the time the status will stuck in "connecting", a while later the caller's status will become "failed" and another phone will just stuck in "connecting" forever. I'm using paid Twilio Stun and Turn

Offer:

```
{ "type":"offer", "sdp":"v=0\\r\\no=- 8557090366646989493 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\\r\\ns=-\\r\\nt=0 0\\r\\na=group:BUNDLE 0\\r\\na=extmap-allow-mixed\\r\\na=msid-semantic: WMS 129ed514-df0a-4571-9989-76c1587d0e5b\\r\\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:Macl\\r\\na=ice-pwd:h82tStrPEYpz6BP6NP43/5i8\\r\\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 93:E5:B3:6C:69:E3:3E:2F:A4:35:89:2E:78:80:E5:6D:D1:B0:E2:67:B5:32:8A:57:95:C2:A5:9E:DE:7B:AF:EC\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=mid:0\\r\\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\\r\\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\\r\\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\\r\\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\\r\\na=sendrecv\\r\\na=msid:129ed514-df0a-4571-9989-76c1587d0e5b 12399eb9-2bc9-4592-b4d1-9a2ad0a24760\\r\\na=rtcp-mux\\r\\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\\r\\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\\r\\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\\r\\na=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2\\r\\na=fmtp:63 111/111\\r\\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\\r\\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\\r\\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\\r\\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\\r\\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\\r\\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\\r\\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\\r\\na=ssrc:1047205720 cname:T+txLzHQE75qWRqE\\r\\na=ssrc:1047205720 msid:129ed514-df0a-4571-9989-76c1587d0e5b 12399eb9-2bc9-4592-b4d1-9a2ad0a24760\\r\\n" }
```

Answer

```
{"sdp": "v=0 o=- 2808091531875933333 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 s=- t=0 0 a=group:BUNDLE 0 a=extmap-allow-mixed a=msid-semantic: WMS 0b75ac9e-a1c1-4512-b0ed-7c7c39ea130c m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126 c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0 a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0 a=ice-ufrag:XXVr a=ice-pwd:r0Qv84goRW840lMT7XXCJqXQ a=ice-options:trickle renomination a=fingerprint:sha-256 F4:19:73:D9:E6:E3:04:31:17:17:23:72:70:E2:D7:C0:E0:08:7D:23:FC:1F:F6:55:AB:2D:E4:E8:A9:8B:A7:13 a=setup:active a=mid:0 a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01 a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid a=sendrecv a=msid:0b75ac9e-a1c1-4512-b0ed-7c7c39ea130c 57f61bc0-4575-45a6-8059-8180f7097a5a a=rtcp-mux a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2 a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1 a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2 a=fmtp:63 111/111 a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000 a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000 a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000 a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000 a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000 a=ssrc:91864977 cname:4dFm+CQwCvVuJ18+ ", "type": "answer"}
```

Log:

```
LOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 ctor +1mLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 addTrack +20msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 createOffer +256msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 createOffer OK +20msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 setLocalDescription +2msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 setLocalDescription OK +42msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 setRemoteDescription +5sLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 ontrack +38msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 setRemoteDescription OK +21msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 addIceCandidate +401msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 addIceCandidate +16msLOG rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 5 addIceCandidate +11ms
```

Comment: Why the ip address is 127.0.0.1?

Comment: no idea, i had connected both real android devices to the wifi. Do you have any idea why it is local IP....?

Comment: What is your environment setup? Do you have a server to exchange the offer and answer between peers?